# Keyboard not showing up on input fields within UIWebView unless Copy is invoked

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I have a UIWebView that for now just loads google. When clicking on the search bar no keyboard pops up, however if I hold down my finger on a link on Google's main page, the 'Open or Copy' dialog pops up and then I'm able to use the keyboard. I'm not sure why it's acting this way.

```
    [LoadGoogle loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Since I realize this can be vague for many, I've made a youtube video showing how this behaves on the iPad. [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrCzSGVR2lI](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrCzSGVR2lI)

Comment: I should also mention that the UIWebView is within a tab bar controller.

Answer (score 3):

i had to add `[_window makeKeyAndVisible];` to AppDelegate to fix this

Answer (score 2):

The solution mentioned here didn't work for me. I had a persistent error that seemed to be an issue with iOS, or at least my build settings. I came up with [a workaround](http://www.wigwag.com/devblog/the-many-solutions-to-the-uiwebviews-non-displaying-keyboard-bug/). If you're still stuck like I was, try this. I think it will work. Here it is briefly. Check out my post if you need more detail.

Put this into your web view's delegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)v shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)r navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)t {

  NSString *requestString = [[r URL] absoluteString];

  if ([requestString hasPrefix: @"yourURLPrefix:"] ) {
      if ([requestString hasPrefix: @"yourURLPrefix:keyboardFix"] ) {
          [v.window makeKeyAndVisible];
      }
}
```

Put this into the onFocus event handler of any input element you need to reliably bring up the keyboard:

```
document.location = "yourURLPrefix:keyboardFix";
```

Comment: After seeing your question on meta it's pretty clear that you get why duplicate answers are not helpful. We undeleted a couple of your posts and threw you a couple of upvotes :). Hopefully this will go towards lifting the answer ban. If you could even go so far as to edit the remaining deleted ones to address anything specific in the OP's question then we'd consider undeleting those as well.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved. The issue was having the "Window" in IB below the controller. Moving the Window up and properly linking it fixed it.